# How to align chapter label on right side and chapter title on left side

Tags: pdftex, chapters, books

I want to align the Chapter Label on right side of the page and chapter title on left side of the page. How can I do this following command:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
```

The output should be like this
[image]

Comment: Please tell us (a) which document class you employ and (b) which packages -- if any -- that can help modify the appearance of headers (such as chapter headers) you load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\sffamily\huge\bfseries}{\filleft\chaptername \thechapter}{4ex}{}[{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\sffamily
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]